# How to use a function as while loop condition?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I have the following code:

```
def funct():
    print("beggining function")
    a = int(input)
    if a == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

while funct():
    #Rest of the code
```

Every time the `while` loop repeats it executes the function, so it prints "beggining function". I want to avoid this, what can I do?

Comment: Remove the `print` statement? Put it somewhere else?

Comment: `while int(input) == 1:`

Comment: @fedorqui please fix the code in an answer, not in an edit of the question.

Comment: @райтфолд Ops sorry! I was working on the original post in a file and didn't notice I did change it. Thanks for notifying.

Answer (score 3):

A `while <condition>` loop works as follows:

1. it checks `condition`.
2. if `condition` evaluates to True, it executes the upcoming code one time. Then it goes back to 1.
3. if `condition` evaluates to False, it skips the upcoming code and goes through the rest of the code.

So what you are seeing here is the intended way for `while` to work.

To prevent this header from being printed every time, just move it out of the `while`:

```
def funct():
    a = int(input)
    if a == 1:
        return True
    return False    # no need to check anymore

print("beggining function")  # here
while funct():
    #Rest of the code
```

Comment: The thing is that the function in my code is a sudoku solver, so it prints the mistakes and returns true, and if the sudoku is solved it returns false, so i want to use only what the function returns to define if the program repeats or finishes.

Comment: i dont know if you want to see the whole code (is a bit long and in spanish), but you would do me a big favor

Comment: Paste it in pastebin.com and I'll have a look.

Comment: I would move line 188 `print("Bienvenido a la experiencia Sudoku en Python",'\n')` above line 186 `while cond:`. This should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try to this

```
def funct():
    print("beggining function")
    a = int(input())
    if a == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
while funct() == 1:
    funct()
```

you enter input 1 loop will continue...

Comment: function is return true than call the function and repeat the loop.

Comment: This will not only still print `beggining function` for every function call, it will now be called twice for each loop.  You should actually read the question.